# Anti Surge Support option in BIOS Setup

Tags: bios, surge-protection

There is an option called *Anti Surge Support* in my BIOS setup. The user manual of my ASUS H87I-PLUS motherboard gives no explanation on it, and I can't get exactly what it is after googling. Could you please tell me simply: what is it used for, or under what circumstances should I enable that option? It is disabled by default.

My rough understanding is, surge happens when voltage supplied is unstable, and a sudden increase of voltage causes a surge. Am I right?

Is there any side effect enabling it regardless whether need it?

Comment: You pretty much have a valid understanding of the feature.  You still want a quality PSU and surge protector.

Comment: I can't think of why you wouldn't use this, especially for a computer. However, as per Ramhound says, I'd favour a surge protector (plug) over this, but make sure the surge protector has an LED to indicate the MOV is working. So, I guess both for the win?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of why you wouldn't use this, especially for a computer. However, as per Ramhound's comments in the OP, I'd also favour a surge protector (plug) over this, but make sure the surge protector has an LED to indicate the MOV is working. And, a cheap surge protector will probably only protect you against small spikes, so do your research into them.
 But, to answer you, I'd use it on the PC as well.